# Is it possible to gracefully handle a Google Maps AJAX request timeout?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

My site uses the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/).  In situations where the connection to Google is slow and the map can't be rendered in a reasonable time, I'd like a Javascript callback method to be called such that I can display a useful message to the user rather than have a 'loading...' message constantly displayed.

Is this achievable?

Comment: When you say "connection to Google" you mean the system that serves the map tiles? Or the system that serves the javascript API file(s)?

Comment: I mean the map rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could have a sleep function that would check if the page has loaded yet, and after a certain time you take some sort of action.

See this [posting](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/javascript-sleep-function-t66049.html) for a situation similar to yours

setTimeout might be useful too.

so, you would have:

```
setTimeout((function() 
           { /* test if the page is loaded, 
                if so, call another function 
                or set a flag to get out*/
           }),2000); //set for 2 seconds
```